# Как решать неравенства js?

Tags: javascript

решил создать небольшую утилитку для решение функций графиков. Но столкнулся с проблемой. Не знаю как решать неравенства с помощью js. К примеру простейшие: x+7>6, x+9=0. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать программно.

Comment: что ты понимаешь под _решением неравенства_?

Comment: @Grundy я бы нарисовал график и закрасил область над или под ним, в зависимости от неравенства, или просто график в случае с =

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, это в принципе логично, но что имел ввиду автор вопроса - неизвестно :)

Comment: Под решением я подразумеваю-узнать чему равен x. Поясню ещё не много, решение неравенств мне нужно чтобы узнать область определения, область значения и т.д.

Comment: @Alik46 приведите пример входных и выходных данных

Comment: @StrangerintheQ к примеру строка «x+8>0»

Comment: @Alik46, а пример выходных данных для этой строки?

Comment: @Grundy ну если исходить из этого примера, то вывести промежуток . То есть «(-8; до плюс бесконечности).

Comment: @Alik46, проблема с разбором формулы или с определением интервалов? или и с тем и с тем?

Comment: @Grundy и с тем и с тем

Comment: @Alik46, для общего случая - весьма не тривиальная задача. Однако для частных случаев, например тех, которые описаны в вопросе вполне можно вручную сделать разбор формулы и вывести решение